# SQL Compact Edition, Unable to connect to local sdf file

Tags: asp.net, sql, visual-studio-2010, database-connection, sql-server-ce

I have a .sdf file in my local directory C:\myDatabase.sdf

In Visual Studio 2010 asp.NET, I added the tables and values etc. I now have a page where I need to connect to the local database on the Default.aspx.cs page.

the code I have is:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=C:\\myDatabase.sdf;");        
conn.Open();
```

The code fails when it tries to run the conn.Open(); The debugger says unable to connect. Heres the error:

"A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)"

Now in the connection string, ive tried almost EVERYTHING! ive tried adding the database name, username, password, server=localhost, mode=exclusive, and many more. it still doesnt work... i cant figure it out. i dont have SQL Server installed i dont think. i just have visual studio 2010 and an sdf file.

I think its trying to connect to a server... but the database file is local? i dont understand. the "server=localhost" didnt work. I dont know how to check wheather the file allows remote connections or not because i dont know how to access the file other than in visual studio!

Can someone please tell me what's going on!

Comment: Did you try connecting to sdf with SQL Management studio?

Comment: no i have not, i dont believe i have management studio:s but ill check. What i dont understand is, when i connect to the sdf file through visual studio, it connects fine, no problem. And in the properties, it gives me the connection string it used to connect. So i copied that exactly (added the back slashes) and it still didnt work

Answer (score 5):

You are using the wrong api. SqlConnection is part of System.Data.SqlClient which is used to access databases running SQL Server. To access a Sql Server Compact db you have to use System.Data.SqlServerCe. You might have to reference a dll to get access to this namespace.

Comment: Thanks very much, this seems logical. But i am an asp c# newb. How do i reference a dll? i managed to find the path to the dll

Comment: Please read the MSDN docs, it explicitely mentions that the namespace is part of the assembly System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx

Comment: I added the dll, no problems:) added the namespace, changed my code. all seemed to look perfect! Then on compile, it said in the runtime error "SQL Server Compact is not intended for ASP.NET development."

Comment: I'm guessing you're using .Net < 4; it seems you need to set some variable to true before using SqlCe; go this link and look at the last remark: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlceconnection(v=VS.90).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Please try with an SqlCeConnection rather than with an SqlConnection.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlceconnection(v=VS.100).aspx